# Is there any way to change the alignment of save and cancel button in v-edit-dialog?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jufgi.jpg)Using below sample code I am able to get the v-edit-dialog on click, the issue is that the save button is on the right side and cancel button is on the left side. Is there any way to make it opposite ?

```
<v-edit-dialog
               :return-value.sync="item[value]"
               @save="save"
               @cancel="cancel"
               large
> {{item[value]}}
    <template v-slot:input>
        <v-text-field
                v-model="item[value]"
                label="Edit"
                single-line
        ></v-text-field>
    </template>
</v-edit-dialog>
```